# No puedo instalar el manifest.json para utilizar service worker

Tags: javascript, json, service-workers, manifest

estoy creando un manifest.json para empezar a usar service worker, ya agrege la ruta  al head del index.html, tambien ya tengo la informacion json del manifest pero cuando hago un reporte en el apartado de Lighthouse en Chrome, en los resultados del reporte me aparece este motivo del error "No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest."

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como se soluciona esto, estaria agredcido, les pasare el codigo de la pagina en github para que la vean:
https://github.com/webahna/serviceWorkerError

Answer (score 0):

En tu script `js/app.js` tienes comentado el código que en teoría registraría el ServiceWorker. No basta con el manifest para que esto ocurra.

Adicionalmente, ese código dice:

```
if('servicesWorker' in navigator){
  ....
}
```

Pero el api es `serviceWorker`, en singular.

Corrigiendo eso y descomentando ese código, Lighthouse sí reconoce el sitio como PWA, con la salvedad que no es instalable (porque tu SW no está manejando el escenario sin conexión)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]